# Spring Boot - Convert Jar Packaging to War Packaging

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, war

I'm working on a web application build with the Spring Boot-Framework... Comming to end, I wanted to start my application from terminal with

> java -jar application.jar

Then I identify that jar-files can not handle JSP-Files. With this mind I edited my POM-file from Maven like this here:

```
<project>
  ....
  <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Application</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ....
</project>
```

When building the application this error-statement is shown:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Building Testbackend 0.1.0
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Downloading:
>   file://C://mod_repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.6/maven-war-plugin-2.6.pom
>   Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils   at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.resolveDestinationPath(FileWagon.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.resourceExists(FileWagon.java:265)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:577)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
>     ... 7 more

Do someone know this error-statement in combination with war-files?

Comment: I think you are approaching this problem from the wrong end. Although you can convert your Spring Boot application to a war, why not rather find out how to package the JSP files?

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this for a personal project. You need to do some changes:

1. Add some dependencies to pom:

   - **groupId:** `org.springframework.boot`
   - **artifactId:** `spring-boot-starter-web`
   - **groupId:** `javax.servlet`
   - **artifactId:** `jstl`
2. Change the package *jar* to *war*: `<packaging>war</packaging>`
3. Extend from `SpringBootServletInitializer` your '`SpringBootWebApplication`' class.
4. Create the following folders structure to add the `*.jsp` files : `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/`
5. In `/src/main/resources/static/` folder you can add the `*.css` files.
6. In **application.properties** file add the following:

   - `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/`
   - `spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`

I used the following references:

- [Spring Boot example JSP](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)
- [Convert JAR to WAR](http://www.shristitechlabs.com/converting-a-spring-boot-jar-application-into-war/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment but here's a resource that I think will help: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Select the "Packaging executable jar and war files with Maven" link. I hope this points you in the right direction.